# Building a Tray Application using Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, system-tray

Using .NET Core and Xamarin I thought about building an application that would run on both Windows and macOS environments.

The .NET Core part would be used for all backend stuff and provide its functionality as a REST API.  .NET Core however, does not have any support for building native UI applications (WPF, ...) so that's a no-go for building a tray application.

So I thought about using Xamarin for this.  But I can't seem to figure out if this is at all possible.  Nor can I find any leads on how to get started.

Some alternatives I've not yet further investigated:

- Mono, but that doesn't have any integration with VS2017 so that's out...
- QT, but that's aimed at C++, so that's out as well
- Java, but then why bother using .NET Core in the first place...
- Electron.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, `Xamarin.Forms` will not officially support WPF till `3.0`.

re: https://blog.xamarin.com/glimpse-future-xamarin-forms-3-0/

In terms of a Tray app, that is native Windows code and would not be a part of `Xamarin.Forms` UI code, but the native Windows code that would show/hide your app's UI (assumably Xamarin.Forms based)

For macOS, `Xamarin.Forms` is supported via `Xamarin.Mac`, and is currently in a "preview" release.

As far as the equivalent of a tool tray app on macOS, in `Xamarin.Mac` you can create a item (icon and/or text based) in the system status bar.

Typically this is done in the `NSApplicationDelegate.DidFinishLaunching` and is easy as:

```
statusItem = NSStatusBar.SystemStatusBar.CreateStatusItem(NSStatusItemLength.Variable);
statusItem.Button.Image = new NSImage("moviemadness_icon_dark.png")
{
    Template = true
};
statusItem.Button.Action = new Selector("StatusItemButtonAction:");
```

In this example, any time the icon/text in the status is tapped, the `StatusItemButtonAction` method is triggered and it either terminates itself if you were holding the control key down at the same time, otherwise it runs the `StatusBarPopOver` which in my case constructs a `NSPopover` and shows an embedded `Xamarin.Forms` `TabbedPage` UI that shows the mobile app server status, current users of the app, the app analytics, etc...

```
[Action("StatusItemButtonAction:")]
public void StatusItemButtonAction(NSStatusBarButton sender)
{                                     
    var currentEvent = NSApplication.SharedApplication.CurrentEvent;
    if (currentEvent.ModifierFlags.HasFlag(NSEventModifierMask.AlternateKeyMask) || 
        currentEvent.ModifierFlags.HasFlag(NSEventModifierMask.ControlKeyMask))
        NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(this);
    else
        StatusBarPopOver();
}
```